# Does SharePoint online support Auto Translation capability?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

I am reading about defining multiple languages for SharePoint online , and i found this official documentations @ https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-multilingual-sharepoint-sites-pages-and-news-2bb7d610-5453-41c6-a0e8-6f40b3ed750c . but this process has those 2 main drawbacks:-

1. Seems to be a bit manual and time consuming.
2. Does not support translation list views and modern web parts.

so can we have auto translation feature inside SharePoint Online? to auto translate everything based on user selected language?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, display language of user interface elements changes automatically after users change their personal language and region settings. As a translator, you can choose to translate manually for those elements which you think is not good by machine(auto) translation.

Comment: what i mean by auto translating, is that if we allow the SharePoint site to have multiple languages drop-down, and the user change the language selection to auto translate the pages without having to create 2 version of each page? i am not taking about changing the user profile personal language ...